# New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment cmdlet usage

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-role-environment

I am trying to figure out how to use the PowerShell cmdlet New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment to add a group to an app role.

In the AzureAD portal, I would select: enterprise applications > app_name > users and groups > add user/group, then select the group name and the app role.

When I do this in the portal with the app, group, and app role I use below, it completes successfully.

The best way I can tell from the documentation below to run this is something like:

```
New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectId -Id $objectId -PrincipalId $principalId -ResourceId $resourceId
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadgroupapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0

where:

```
ObjectId = name of the group being assigned to the app role
Id = not sure here, but some examples point to using the group object ID again
PrincipalId = app object id
ResourceId = app role object id
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing
> NewGroupAppRoleAssignment  Code: Request_BadRequest Message: Not a
> valid reference update. RequestId:
> fb8145c9-8fb4-4d6d-92b7-f48a81ef1e2d DateTimeStamp: Thu, 07 Jul 2022
> 15:27:10 GMT HttpStatusCode: BadRequest HttpStatusDescription: Bad
> Request HttpResponseStatus: Completed At
> \truenas\IT\Scripts\AzureAD\AzureAD-Add App Role to Group Test.ps1:12
> char:1
>
> - New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectId -Id $id -Princi ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment], ApiException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewGroupAppRoleAssignment
>   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the correct values to use for the parameters in `New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment`

```
ObjectId = Group object ID    
Id = App role ID    
PrincipalId = Group object ID    
ResourceId = Enterprise Application object ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and answer! I definitely had that switched up, works great now! Thank you again!